# React Native - Sentry.captureException not working

Tags: react-native, sentry

I'm trying to use **Sentry.captureException** in my React Native app, but it's not working properly.
I'm receiving the eventId, but there is no issues on Sentry website.

Here is the code:

```
const eventId = Sentry.captureException(new Error("Testing"));
console.log(eventId); /// ccfa8f3799524c8ea9e138fb792******
```

PS. Native errors are working fine, if I try `throw('Testing')` it works.

PS. **Android only**, iOS is working fine

- **RN**: 0.63.3
- **@sentry/react-native**: 2.0.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this:

```
Sentry.captureEvent({
    event_id: <error_id>,
    message: <message>,
    extra: <data_in_json>,
});
```